# How to add x label in multiple histograms quickly in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I see this code :

`list <-lapply(1:ncol(mtcars), function(col) ggplot2::qplot(mtcars[[col]], geom = "histogram",binwidth = 1)) cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = list)`

surggest by Paul Endymion to respond to "Plotting multiple histograms quickly in R".

I try that code, and it work well. But, I don't know how to add x labels in that code because all histograms are labeled `histdata[[col]]`. Can you help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `xlab = names(mtcars)[col])` you can access the names of the dimensions

```
list <-lapply(1:ncol(mtcars), function(col) ggplot2::qplot(mtcars[[col]], geom = "histogram",binwidth = 1, xlab = names(mtcars)[col])) 
    cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `list` as a variable name since `list()` is the constructor for list objects. It will only lead to confusion.

You can simply use the `xlab` argument of `qplot`:

```r
l <-lapply(1:ncol(mtcars), function(col) ggplot2::qplot(mtcars[[col]], geom = "histogram",binwidth = 1, xlab = names(mtcars)[col])) 
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = l)
```

However, since you are using `ggplot`, it would be more elegant to go with a `tidyverse` solution to begin with:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  gather("var", "val") %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(aes(val), bins = 10) +
  facet_wrap(~var, scales = "free")
```